# How do you use the water cannon in Marvel Spider Man ultimate power?

Tags: android, spider-man-ultimate-power

One daily quest I get in  Marvel Spider Man ultimate power from android to win a jewel, it's to use the water cannon. But I've passed many stages and I've never seen it. Where's that? Is it an item  you have to buy? Is it a secret item? How do you use the water cannon?